# How do I get audio working from inside LXD container?

Tags: raspbian-buster, pulseaudio

I'm following the instructions in this blog entry:
https://blog.simos.info/running-x11-software-in-lxd-containers/

where the container connects to the unix socket on the host:
`unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native`

but this unix socket does not exist on the host.

How do I create it? Or is there a better alternative method?

I'm running Raspbian buster on Pi 4